# UIPickerview display more options (rows)

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I couldn't find it anywhere...

I have the option to expand a bit the UIPickerView to show more than 5 (almost 7) rows it displays.

numberOfRowsInComponent is usually 20-30 in my case so if I am able to show the user some more, it is nicer

I can't to that?

Comment: Post your current code...

Comment: I get what you are saying, assume numberOfRowsInComponent returns a lot more (20-30)

Comment: What is the current height of the picker? If you have so many items - rethink your UI, show a modal view controller with a table...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [UIKit documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIPickerView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIPickerView):

> Appearance of Picker Views (Programmatic)
>
> You cannot customize the appearance of picker views.

Comment: It should be noted that you can change the height of a `UIPickerView` - it has 3 different heights, `162`, `180` and `216`.

Comment: @rich - it is 162 (in the storyboard at least). How can I change it?